# How to use Go interfaces to test with the Google API Golang lib?

Tags: go, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use interfaces to test code that uses [google's drive api lib](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/drive/v2/drive-gen.go).

```
type MyFile struct {
  DownloadUrl string `json:"downloadUrl,omitempty"`
}

type MyFilesGetCall interface {
  Do() (*MyFile, error)
  // Do() (*drive.File, error) // this DOES work
}

type MyFilesService interface {
  Get(string) *MyFilesGetCall
  // Get(string) *drive.FilesGetCall // this DOES work
}

func GetInfo(id string, myService MyFilesService) {
  myService.Get(id).Do()
}

func main() {
  drive, _ := drive.New(new(http.Client))
  GetInfo("id", drive.Files)
}
```

When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
$ go run so.go
./so.go:24: cannot use drive.Files (type *drive.FilesService) as type MyFilesService in argument to GetInfo:
        *drive.FilesService does not implement MyFilesService (wrong type for Get method)
                have Get(string) *drive.FilesGetCall
                want Get(string) *MyFilesGetCall
./so.go:28: fService.Get(id).Do undefined (type *MyFilesGetCall has no field or method Do)
```

It seems that interfaces only work 1 level deep.

Can anyone recommend an alternative approach for mocking this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that interfaces only work 1 level deep.

Go has no notion of co/ntravariance. The signature for `Get` is incompatible with the `MyFilesService` interface. As your error message told you:

```
*drive.FilesService does not implement MyFilesService (wrong type for Get method)
    have Get(string) *drive.FilesGetCall
    want Get(string) *MyFilesGetCall
```

> Can anyone recommend an alternative approach for mocking this dependency?

Change `MyFilesService` to something that `*drive.FilesService` actually implements.

Comment: *drive.FilesService has a Do method which returns (*drive.File, error), so why can't I swap it with MyFilesService the following?

`type MyFilesGetCall interface {
  Do() (*drive.File, error)
}

type MyFilesService interface {
  Get(string) *MyFilesGetCall
}`